# Null context in onResponse callback method retrofit android

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, retrofit

I have a DialogFragment. When i click the OK button, i execute a retrofit call to my api like this

```
 @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                int code = response.code();
                if (code == 200) {
                    LoginResponse lr = response.body();
                    if (lr.getError()) {
                        Utils.showToast(getActivity(), "Error! Los datos son incorrectos.");
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ConfigGeneralActivity.class));
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: " + String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

at this part of the code, getActivity() is null.

Another option is to pass the context from the oncreatedialog to this callback, but when i do this, i got the error that says activity is not attached to fragment.

I know i can implement Otto but it's too complex for what i want to do. I just want to start a new activity from a retrofit callback inside a DialogFragment.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think your fragment calling this method destroyed, so fragment is not attached to activity when method responses.

Comment: Try to use application context in case of getActivity() is null

Comment: @Jai but to call applicationContext i have to call getActivity().getApplicationContext(), and getActivity() is null..

Comment: @MaximilianoPoggio : No I meant you have to create Application class which will give you global context not the context related to that activity which is already distroyed

Answer (score 1):

You need to runOnUiThread to get the Context inside OnResponse Callback

Like:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {    
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //your code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue, you are using getActivity() to call runOnUiThread() and getActivity can be null